# Why is unused Kotlin function failing at load time?

Tags: kotlin

If I include the following Kotlin function in any Kotlin file, it will cause a failure to load that file. I'd like to understand why.

```
fun optionalUnitReturningOptionalNothing(): Unit? {
    fun localOptionalNothing(): Nothing? {
        return null
    }
    return localOptionalNothing()
}
```

Here is a sample error message:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class NullAssignTestKt
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    NullAssignTestKt.optionalUnitReturningOptionalNothing()Lkotlin/Unit; @3: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Void' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'kotlin/Unit' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @3
    flags: { }
    locals: { }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Void' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b800 0bb0
```

Moving the internal function outside does not fix the problem, however, the following compiles, loads and executes without a problem:

```
fun optionalNothing(): Nothing? { return null }
fun optionalUnit(): Unit? { return null }
val lambdaOptionalUnitReturningOptionalNothing: () -> Unit? = { optionalNothing() }

fun main() {
    optionalNothing() ?: println("optional nothing worked")
    optionalUnit() ?: println("optional unit worked")
    lambdaOptionalUnitReturningOptionalNothing() ?: println("lambda worked")
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to accomplish by returning nullable `Nothing`?

Comment: I try to limit use of exceptions and often use a `null` return from functions as a "should not happen" equivalent. In these cases, I like to log something at the same time and found it convenient to use `return someFunctionThatReturnsNull()`. The only type I could find that's compatible with all nullable types is `Nothing?`.

Comment: Whether it's a valid programming pattern or not, the Kotlin compiler should never generate bytecode that causes a VerifyError. I'd suggest raising a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

The first version doesn't work because you're trying to return `Nothing?` from a function whose return type is `Unit`. Kotlin isn't detecting the problem at compile-time, but it is detecting it at runtime.

The second version works because you're not actually returning the value of the inner function call. `optionalNothing()` runs, and then `optionalUnit()` returns `Unit`.

```
    private fun optionalNothing(): Nothing? { return null }
    private fun optionalUnit(): Unit? { return null }

    /**
     * This wont load because you can't actually return Nothing?.
     */
    fun optionalUnitReturningOptionalNothing(): Unit? {
        fun localOptionalNothing(): Nothing? {
            return null
        }
        return localOptionalNothing() 
    }

    /**
     * This is fine because it returns Unit.
     * optionalNothing gets called, but it has no return value.
     */
    private val lambdaOptionalUnitReturningOptionalNothing1: () -> Unit? = { optionalNothing() }

    /**
     * This wont even compile.
     */
    private val lambdaOptionalUnitReturningOptionalNothing2: () -> Unit? = { return optionalNothing() }

    /**
     * Neither will this.
     */
    private val lambdaOptionalUnitReturningOptionalNothing3: () -> Unit? = optionalNothing()
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the response. You stated that the problematic function returns `Unit`, but it actually returns `Unit?`, for which `null` is a valid value. As far as the lambda version is concerned, lambdas return the last value in their sequence, so that function is indeed returning the result of `optionalNothing()`, namely `null`. `lambda...2` won't compile because `return` statements are not legal in lambdas. `lambda...3` won't compile because `optionalNothing()` is of type `Nothing?`, which isn't a valid lambda.

Comment: I'm actually pretty new to Kotlin, but here goes. 
```private val lambdaOptionalUnitReturningOptionalNothing1: () -> Unit? = { optionalNothing() }```


is basically


```private val lambdaOptionalUnitReturningOptionalNothing1: () -> Unit? = {  }```



`optionalNothing()` is not being interpreted as a the return value of the lambda. It's just being treated as a statement.

Comment: Again, lambdas return their final expression per the documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression

Comment: But there is no final expression because functions that return Nothing don't return anything.

Comment: Whether it's a function or a lambda, this is about a return type of `Nothing?`, not  `Nothing`. Functions/lambdas of that sort can return `null`.